# clang error when installing MYSQL-python on Lion-mountain (Mac OS X 10.8)

Tags: python, mysql, django, pip, mysql-python

When I try installing `mysql-python` using below command,

`macbook-user$ sudo pip install MYSQL-python`

I get these messages:

> /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/pyconfig.h:891:1: warning: this is the location of the previous definition
>
> /usr/bin/lipo: /tmp/_mysql-LtlmLe.o and /tmp/_mysql-thwkfu.o have the same architectures (i386) and can't be in the same fat output file
>
> **clang: error: lipo command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)**
>
> error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1

Does anyone know how to solve this problem? Help me please!

Answer (score 0):

At first glance it looks like damaged pip package. Have you tried easy_install instead with the same package?

Comment: I tried pip install command first but failed.. After that I re-tried with easy_install command .. but also failed too!

Comment: And what was the result of it? The same failure?

Comment: Yes, result was same. failure... Is there any solution about this??

Comment: What is the Mysql version you've installed (32/64 bit, which version number) and have you tried installing MYSQL-python from source?

Comment: I'm using 5.1.44 version of XAMPP tool. I downloaded at here(http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-macosx.html#849).

Comment: Grab the source code of that python library here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/mysql-python/files/mysql-python/1.2.3/ and follow the instructions to compile and install it from source, instead by using the package.

Comment: Oh! I solved this problem!! I upgrade python to lastest version(2.7.3) and run MYSQL server. And then I successfully install MYSQL-python!. It works well!

Thankyou SpankMe!

Comment: I'm using latest Version 4.5.2